# Having Issues With Sorting CSV Files In Python (Sorting by first name but also printing second name and the highest of three scores)

Tags: python, sorting, csv

## Explanation

For a school project I have been asked to let a teacher view some scores in a few ways, although whenever I run the program I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\shs-sr-fap-01\11-62$\School\Computing\A453\Task 3\Teacher Score Viewer.py", line 53, in <module>
    byalphabet()
  File "\\shs-sr-fap-01\11-62$\School\Computing\A453\Task 3\Teacher Score Viewer.py", line 36, in byalphabet
    for row in sorted(byalphabet, key=lambda x:x(int(x[2]), int(x[3]), int(x[4])), reverse = True):
  File "\\shs-sr-fap-01\11-62$\School\Computing\A453\Task 3\Teacher Score Viewer.py", line 36, in <lambda>
    for row in sorted(byalphabet, key=lambda x:x(int(x[2]), int(x[3]), int(x[4])), reverse = True):
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

This is my code - I have a menu system that asks you how you want to sort it, for now I'm not doing the class part of the menu. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Ask me if you need anything explained.

> (In case you need to know what resides on each row of my CSV file -
>   First name, last name, Score 1, score 2, score 3, Class (A, B or C
>   [Just ignore this for now])

```
import csv
#To Do List - byaverage, byalphabetically, byscore

def sortmenu():
    print("============================")
    print("How do you wish to sort the results?")
    print("============================")
    print("Average Score [Enter 1]")
    print("Alphabetically [Enter 2]")       
    print("Highest Score [Enter 3]")
    sortchoice = input("Please enter 1, 2 or 3:")
    return sortchoice

def classmenu():
    print("========================")
    print("Choose your class!")
    print("========================")
    print("Class A [Enter A]")
    print("Class B [Enter B]")       
    print("Class C [Enter C]")
    classchoice = input("Please enter A, B or C: ")
    return classchoice

#byaverage
def byaverage():
    f = open 
#byhighest
#x:x[0]    
#byaplhabet 
def byalphabet():
    frogs = open('Classes.csv')
    csv_frogs = csv.reader(frogs)
    byalphabet = []
    for row in csv_frogs:
        byalphabet.append(row)
    for row in sorted(byalphabet, key=lambda x:x(int(x[2]), int(x[3]), int(x[4])), reverse = True): 
        print (row)


#PROGRAM START - This Is The Password System - Teacher is the password
TeacherPassword=input("Please enter the teacher password\n")
if(TeacherPassword == "Teacher"):
    classchoice = ""
    while(classchoice not in ['A', 'B', 'C']):
        classchoice = classmenu()
        if(classchoice in ['A', 'B', 'C']):
            sortchoice = ""
            while(sortchoice not in ['1', '2', '3']):
                sortchoice = sortmenu()
            if sortchoice == "1":
                byaverage()
            elif sortchoice == "2":
                byalphabet()
            elif sortchoice == "3":
                byscore()
        else:
            print("Nope, thats wrong - please enter A, B or C ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error:

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

from the line:

```
for row in sorted(byalphabet, key=lambda x:x(int(x[2]), int(x[3]), int(x[4])), reverse = True):
```

This is because the elements of `byalphabet` are not functions, yet you are attempting to call them with `x(...)`. I'm guessing you meant to have a tuple instead:

```
for row in sorted(byalphabet, key=lambda x:(int(x[2]), int(x[3]), int(x[4])), reverse = True):
```

Also, it is not good to use the same name for a function and a list:

```
def byalphabet():
...
byalphabet = []
```